Difference equation of a digital power supply compensator implement in C++ using Fixed Point Math
So, I've found myself having to translate a continuous time domain system into a Z-transform.
I have a SEPIC on my hand, whose GVD transfer function I know. I have a MATLAB script that allows me to check the analog compensator that I would use to compensate the GVD (H(s),Vm,DC gain) all factored in.
The last thing I needed to do was, translate the s domain to z domain using the Tustin substitution and voila, I got my self the following difference equation of a PID compensator
vc[n] = Kc1*vc[n-1] + Kc2*vc[n-2] + Ke1*ve[n] + Ke2*ve[n-1] + Ke3*ve[n-2]
n denotes the present sampling period, n-1 the previous one and n-2 the second previous. Kex and Kcx are just coefficients of the PID compensator that I generated from my MATLAB script.
The challenge now is that I have to implement this using fixed point math; the micrcontroller that I'm using is C2000 series from TI and doesn't have hardware floating point engine. Implementing floating point in this architecture will drastically slow down the loop, thereby adding even more phase delay.
With all this said, here is a snippet of my code that I'm implementing. I've left off the extra fluff that's in my code but most of it is just setting up variables and giving the correct bits and sizes etc. I'm not so experienced with C++ code and hence the query:
Based on the code below, have I implemented my difference equation correctly while appropriately using the scaling factor that is used for fixed point math?
    ADC_Voltage = ADC_readResult(myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_2);
    ve=(int32_t)Vref*kscale-((int32_t)ADC_Voltage)*kscale;
    ve_intermediate=((int64_t)Ke1*(int64_t)ve+(int64_t)Ke2*(int64_t)ve2+(int64_t)Ke3* 
    (int64_t)ve3)/kscale;
    vc_intermediate=((int64_t)Kc1*(int64_t)vc1+(int64_t)Kc2*(int64_t)vc2)/kscale;//


    vc=vc_intermediate+ve_intermediate;//n
    duty_limit_reached=0;

    ve3=ve2;
    ve2=ve;
    vc2=vc1;
    vc1=vc;

    //DutyCycle = (uint32_t)(vc/kscale);
    PWM_setCmpA(myPwm, DutyCycle/7);

    // Clear ADCINT1 flag reinitialize for next SOC
    ADC_clearIntFlag(myAdc, ADC_IntNumber_1);
    // Acknowledge interrupt to PIE
    PIE_clearInt(myPie, PIE_GroupNumber_10);
    //GPIO_Toggle to verify the ADC sampling interval
    GPIO_toggle(myGpio, GPIO_Number_19);
    ((GPIO_Obj *)myGpio)->GPATOGGLE = 0x00080000;
    return;


Please state the scaling factor kscale and the range of ADC results.

(A kscale of 7 may be much slower than 8 (1 << 3), which in turn may (or may not) be not as fast as 1 << 8 or 1 << 16.)

(There is a specific DSP SE site.)

You ask to see if there is something wrong in a snippet of non-documented code, without telling any details how you expect it to work, such as range of expected input and output numbers. In itself the code is not about electrical engineering but implementing what I assume is a 2nd order biquad filter with fixed point math (there is the FIR and IIR part). It also does not look C++ but plain C.

There is correctness (which I don't intend to address beyond found nothing wrong), and there is avoiding effort.
First off, when doing lengthy processing in an interrupt routine (is this code part of one?), be sure to know the consequences of interrupts missed.
Without inspecting the assembler code generated (be sure to specify code improvement/"optimisation" (often "-O2") and the exact processor model):

rather than scaling minuend and subtrahend, scale the difference:
ve = ((int32_t)Vref - ADC_Voltage) * kscale;
Better yet, incorporate kscale into the constants.
avoid runtime type conversion of constants
rather than scaling each v?_intermediate individually, scale the sum:
vc = (vc_intermediate + ve_intermediate) / kscale;

